# Node.js, node-inspector, JavaScript, Google Chrome: debug workflow

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, debugging, node-inspector

I start a debug session like this:

```
$ node-debug -p 8082 try-debug.js 8081
```

Then I go to the Node Inspector tab in Google Chrome. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to abort the debug session and/or reload modified source short of restarting manually the node-debug server *and* reloading the Node Inspector tab.

What is the right way?

Comment: Have you tried [iron-node](https://github.com/s-a/iron-node)?

Comment: Never heard of it :) . Looks very promising, even from the very bottom of the learning curve.

Comment: While fast and beautiful, iron-node is virtually undocumented. I run _$ iron-node myfile.js_, ironNode window opens, and runs the script. I'd prefer it just loaded, and no more, so I could set breakpoints and start debugging. I've no idea how to go about it.

Comment: _$ node debug try-debug.js_ works just like any debugger. https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html there are There are _run, restart_ and _kill_ commands which work just as expected, no surprises. Meanwhile, this basic debugger is just another frontend to V8, like Google Chrome DevTools and iron-node, which I can't manage :( .

Comment: Looks like _debugger;_ statement in the source code is essential. Is it really so? With it, Ctrl-R also works. Is there any how-to? Google is less than helpful.

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov just place a ```debugger;``` statement where you you want to stop. Have you seen this ironnode how to video?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxq6zdfJeNI I ever thought its so amazing easy... But we like to get better docs so feel free to contribute at  https://github.com/s-a/iron-node or submit any question as issue there.